# Disabling a HTML element rendered by a tierce library component without having access to the source code in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my project, i have to use a component that comes from an external library. I load it through cdnjs. The problem is that this component is not customizable and i want to disable an HTLM element rendered by him on demand.

I was thinking of using vanilla JS to query the DOM element manually in it's parent component but it seems odd doing this in react.

Ideally i would like to pass a props to it like this, but i don't have access to the imported Component code.

```
<MyImportedComponent disabled={this.state.invalid} />
```

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, there is no official way to do this with React. Without access to a component's source code, you can't modify its output or render logic unless you use jQuery or vanilla JS (or maybe even CSS). Using these methods WOULD be odd in React and generally frowned upon, but if it works, it works.

However, there might be a way to achieve your goal with the specific imported component or codebase you're working with. If you don't or can't include that information, we can't help you much more than general statements (like above).